# Infer correct object from nested type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make Typescript infer the correct object in a switch case and I'm struggling to understand why my scenario does not work (with an object) but does work as expected when it's a union type.

From the playground link:

```
interface Base {
  id: number;
  name:  "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"; // This is type-guarding correctly
  type: {
    id: number;
    name: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d"; // This is NOT type-guarding correctly
  }
}

interface A extends Base {
  name: "a";
  type: {
    id: number;
    name: "a";
  }
  a: {
    b: number;
  }
}

interface B extends Base {
  name: "b";
  type: {
    id: number;
    name: "b";
  }
  b: {
    a: number;
  }
}

interface Generic extends Base {
  name: "c" | "d";
  type: {
    id: number;
    name: "c" | "d";
  }
}

type C = A | B | Generic

function test(t: C) {
  // If you switch the switch case to 't.name'
  switch(t.type.name) {
  // switch(t.name) {
    case "a":
      // This will be properly type-guarded as it will infer A
      console.log(t.a)
      break;
    case "c":
      console.log(t.name);
      break;
    case "b":
      // This will be properly type-guarded as it will infer B
      console.log(t.b);
      break;
  }
}
```

I have one object that can have different properties depending of the value of `type.name`. I want to, in a switch case, to check for that `type.name` and have typescript understanding which properties I have access based on that.
As per the example, if I do the switch case on `name`, it works as expected.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxURnIBEcHyAPpzR78OCIZyId6yAPTTkAFQAWwDIVVgAngAcIAWgDmFOFCKh9yBAHsoUCAjAAbDU006yeAgWJlKtBkwIQFjZObj4BMRFIiSlZBWVVFWQAOQB5eWRXPUNjUxBzKxs7R2cCAF9cCtxQSFhEFABBZAgAD0gQIlV0LGQPZlYyLkkXbRC%20r1JyajooRk9%20kKG55AqCOHcA5Bofaf9yytxq8Gh4JDRmtogOrswcJiCBiOWsjfnvKb9ZzYfFwWXVravTzrD4zf4HI61U4oADiV2gwAQF3anTQt1692Cg1E4Q4MRGbgxb0mvjB3yxnBxwnx%20yqWWQAGFkABeZBNfiocJwkAIhCHGAUED2YCWECZCAYMAACjAZAZAEoiTI5ABJGDIDSWCjIDAAd2AYAQikyihQeoNRos6LAlmQAHIwAA6H52pjmw2KGWOrLO4KKvpxd1Gr0-f2bBDooYkTYEOJKJL6hwOLYoLRQSw6KBOTKjAxGEwQIjITCEMDIRPJ0AwaBsmMWUUYSwOCCOhyWfReuDyus0WxwADWywIEZ6UWj82HDabLbbHadoaHnl7EAHi5HKA4gnHE7jCXLwCTKeQaYz0GzWTzuULxcSZYrhBA1agaDrVhAjebrfbXpo8sXBGXVcmAqMogA)

Besides using `as` or flattening the object, what other options do I have?

Comment: TypeScript does not support "nested discriminated unions" as described in [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758).  If you want narrowing based on a nested property you'd need to build that functionality yourself with a user-defined type guard function, perhaps as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5O40W) (and note that such type guard functions return only `boolean` so the `switch` needs to be changed to an `if`/`else` chain).  Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I was struggling with what to search for.

What's the advantage of having user-defined type guards (which will always be extra checks on top of the switch-case) when compared to using `as` to define the correct type?

Comment: I'm confused by the question, since it sounds like you're asking why type guarding (the compiler tells you what type something is) is an advantage over type assertions (you tell the compiler what type something is). Every use of a type assertion (`as`) is a potential type safety hole; if you write the wrong thing (like `t as A` in the case where you should have said `t as B`) then the compiler won't catch it. The user-defined type guard is only written once, so as long as you implement that right, then every use of it is just as safe as every other use of it.  Is that what you want to know?

Comment: I see what you mean and your answer makes sense. I'm struggling with the added complexity as, and thinking of the playground example, will have type checks for specific objects but not for others - I wonder if it can get confusing down the line. I do agree that having the compiler do the work for me is the most safe approach - it might be the case that I just have to properly document this scenario in the codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not support "nested" discriminated unions where you use a subproperty to discriminate among members.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758).  So while `C` *is* a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with `name` as the discriminant, you can't use `type.name` as the discriminant.  So you pretty much can't use any of the machinery designed to handle discriminated unions, such as using a `switch` on the discriminant property.

If you want to get the compiler to type guard on subproperties, so that you don't have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or change your object structure, then the only option I can imagine is to write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that performs the narrowing for you.  It could look like this:

```
function hasNestedTypeName<
  T extends { type: { name: string } },
  K extends string
>(t: T, k: K): t is
  T extends { type: { name: infer N } }
  ? K extends N ? T : never
  : never {
  return t.type.name === k
}
```

So if you call `hasNestedTypeName(t, k)` and it returns `true`, then the compiler will narrow `t` to be just those union members whose `type.name` property can accept `k` as a value.  We have to refactor `test` to use `if`/`else` chains instead of `switch` because of the `boolean` return type of type guard functions.  Like this:

```
function test(t: C) {
  if (hasNestedTypeName(t, "a")) {
    // function hasNestedTypeName<C, "a">(t: C, k: "a"): t is A
    t // A
    console.log(t.a)
  } else if (hasNestedTypeName(t, "c")) {
    // function hasNestedTypeName<B | Generic, "c">(t: B | Generic, k: "c"): t is Generic
    t // Generic
    console.log(t.name)
  } else if (hasNestedTypeName(t, "b")) {
    t // B 
    console.log(t.b)
  }
```

This works the same way as your version, more or less (it's actually hard to get the `hasNestedTypeName(t, "c")` to work as desired, since if it returns `false`, the compiler assumes that `t` is *not* a `Generic`, but that's not necessarily the case.  I'd stay away from discriminated unions where the discriminant is itself a union, since it could do weird things).

Whether or not it's worth such a change depends on the use case.  Personally I'd suggest that refactoring the object shape so that the discriminant is at the top level is the best way to go, since it uses the language's strengths instead of trying to work around its weaknesses.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxURkBEc7yAPsuzW592CIfyLt6yAPTTkAFQAWwDIVVgAngAcIAWgDmFOFCKh9yBAHsoUCAjAAbDU006yeAgWJlKtBkwIQFjZ+Ll5+QXCRMXYJKVkFZVUVZAA5AHl5ZFc9Q2NTEHMrGztHZwIAX1wq3FBIWEQUAEFkCAAPSBAiVXQsZA9mVg4uRgIc9wDCUnJqOihRzyCh0MkmKoI4Cc9kGh9Z-0rq3FrwaHgkNFaOiC6ezBwmJZCBVbHtEIGvad85hcDgjiCBbrHZbTybGZ+eZrI4nernFAAcRu0GACCunW6aHu-UeAP4oiicRc7zBXz2UL+g2ehOExMONRyyAAwsgALzIFp8VDhZEgVEIY4wCggezASwgZCKTCpCAYSBEeTvVLBAA8TCy7Uxqmw2VJ-WpZHlUDMyAqZoANEwANIYm5Y41mXAAPgAFGAyPILcgANZka0ASjIYDUGrttwN4wNTzIoBg0DSZrNTAA-MhbVr7apUsg01kfBAAG7QJgF4tQXEEWxgChQSVgAB0OQbT3ZbI5PthwtFYHF9blYHdZGZAcrMjkAEkYMgNJYKMgMAB3YBgBCKbKKFBLldriw4sCWZAAckbTyPTGA09d0owsvlEEVyuC7u9nHYAdHn3HyG7YolUplAcHyVHQVVYVVmVfLg3Q9FlvT9FYg2yNROUmEMEiaSYrBADBLAcCAGwcSx9HdBs4ADNZWgcPpL2Qa9APvR9QOfMBX1ED8xwIBJf17f8bzvBUQIgMCIFVHk+D5AU2PYGCyHE5BJJNBB4I4djgxQxS0TQ79NMFbZsNw-DCOI0ingoyoqJoq9+KApjhJY19BA4r90LkHksIlQyCKIkjGxoczkwqIA)